# Strip/replace spaces within a string

Tags: ruby, regex

Given a string `"5 900 000"`

I want to get rid of the spaces using `gsub` with the following pattern:

```
gsub(/\s/, '')
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Nor does:

```
gsub(' ', '')
```

Comment: Not sure if that was intentional, but there shouldn't be a period after gsub. "gsub(' ', '')" not "gsub.(' ', '')"

Answer (score 34):

If you want to do the replacement in place, you need to use:

```
str.gsub!(/\s/,'')
```

Alternatively, gsub returns the string with the replacements

```
str2 = str.gsub(/\s/,'')
```

**EDIT**: Based on your answer, it looks like you have some unprintable characters embedded in the string, not spaces.  Using [/\D/](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/UsersGuide/rg/regexp.html) as the search string may be what you want.  The following will match any non-digit character and replace it with the empty string.

```
str.gsub!(/\D/,'')
```

Answer (score 14):

```
>> "5 900 00".gsub(' ','')
=> "590000"
```

Is it really a string?

.gsub returns the value, if you want to change the variable try .gsub!(" ", "")

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the situation, you may not need a regular expression. `String#tr` should work well if you want to replace a single space with the empty string:

```
telemachus ~ $ irb
>> "500 500 12".tr(' ', '')
=> "50050012"
>> "500 500 12".tr!(' ', '')
=> "50050012"
```

As with `gsub` and `gsub!`, the `!` method makes the change in place as opposed to returning the changed result. I don't know which you want here.

In a case like this, `tr` seems more straightforward to me. I'm not looking for optimization, but it is good to remember that there are lots of string methods *other* than regular expressions.

Comment: Not sure if `tr` is a good option? `Translates str in place, using the same rules as String#tr. Returns str, or nil if no changes were made.` So if the string doesn't match anything, it will return nil.

Comment: @23inhouse I'm not sure what you mean. For the first `tr`, I think you mean `tr!`. (The whole difference between `tr` and `tr!` is that `tr` does **not** make the changes in place. As for returning `nil`, whether or not that's ok depends on the larger application. The op hasn't given us enough to go on. It might be fine or it might be a mistake.

Comment: true, i thought it worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest doing `str.gsub!(/\s+/, '')` for efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Try this hope this will helpful :

```
2.2.1 :001> str= "  Jai   Kumar rajput ";
  # "  Jai   Kumar rajput "
2.2.1 :001> str.squish.downcase.tr(" ","");
  # "JaiKumarRajput"
```

Answer (score 1):

`"5 900 000".gsub(/\s/,'')` works fine

From what I see you wrote gsub **dot** (foo,bar) where it must be **string.gsub(foo,bar)**

Answer (score 0):

```
print "5 900 000".gsub(/\s/, '')
```

Works for me.

Are you affecting the result to the variable ?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean

```
str.gsub!.(/\s/,'')
```

with the exclamation mark?

Answer (score 0):

The funny thing is that when I print the string i get

697\302\240000

but what gets to the database is: 697 000.
I know that patterns i have given should work as well as your suggestions, but this seems to be a little bit 'dodgy' case :-)

Comment: in this case try str.gsub!(/\D/,'')